# creating objects in R with for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

(I've tried searching for this, so apologies if I missed it somewhere and it has been answered before):

I have a data frame with the following variables:
    data<- data.frame(country, year, fdi, id)

```
**country  /  year  /  fdi  /  id**   
Germany  /  1991  /  1.1  /  1  
Germany  /  1992  /  1.4  /  1   
Germany  /  1993  /  1.3  /  1  
Spain    /  1991  /  1.2  /  2  
Spain    /  1992  /  2.3  /  2  
Spain    /  1993  /  2.4  /  2  
Greece   /  1991  /  1.4  /  3  
Greece   /  1992  /  1.7  /  3  
Greece   /  1993  /  1.8  /  3
```

What I need to do is to create objects for each country that store the the `fdi` values for a given country for all observed years.

For example:

```
fdigdp.germany = data$fdi [data$country=="Germany"]
fdigdp.germany = as.ts(fdi.germany)
```

...gives me an object that is a vector with the values 1.1, 1.4, 1.3.

Is there a good way to automate this, possibly through a for loop, so that I get one object per country with the fdi values. It would be a plus if the objects derived their names from the countries they represent, but even just an index number (such as the "id" variable) would work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You definitely don't want to create many objects in a loop (see [keep data out of your variable names](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html)) for one description as to why not). What are you trying to do? Is it just so you can look at them?

Answer (score 0):

You could aggregate over the frame and generate a row per group, using the `c` function to combine the values to a vector;

```
#    country year fdi id
# 1  Germany 1991 1.1  1
# 2  Germany 1992 1.4  1
# 3  Germany 1993 1.3  1
# 4    Spain 1991 1.2  2
# 5    Spain 1992 2.3  2
# 6    Spain 1993 2.4  2
# 7   Greece 1991 1.4  3
# 8   Greece 1992 1.7  3
# 9   Greece 1993 1.8  3
# 10  Greece 1994 1.9  3

df2 <- setNames(aggregate(df$fdi, list(df$country), FUN=c), c('country','fdi_vector'))

#   country         fdi_vector
# 1 Germany      1.1, 1.4, 1.3
# 2  Greece 1.4, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9
# 3   Spain      1.2, 2.3, 2.4
```